# HTML/CSS Navigation dropdown and sub dropdown not showing up when the site goes responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am having trouble with the navigation bar when the site goes responsive.
when clicking the drop-down menu the div seems to vanish. not sure if this is something to do with the CSS or jQuery.

> Demo Here: https://jsfiddle.net/0nxfys9s/

---

HTMl (all the li classes are generated by WordPress, sorry)

```
<nav class="clearfix">

            <div class="menu-main-menu-container"><ul id="menu-main-menu-1" class="menu"><li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-86"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-148"><a href="#">other tab</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-149"><a href="#">other tab</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-320"><a href="#">other sub tab</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-321"><a href="#">other sub tab</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-322"><a href="#">other sub tab</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-323"><a href="#">other sub tab</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-326"><a href="#">other sub tab</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-324"><a href="#">other sub tab</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-327"><a href="#">other sub tab</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-328"><a href="#">other sub tab</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-136"><a href="#">other tab</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-147"><a href="#">other tab</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-7"><a href="#">other tab</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-58"><a href="#">other tab</a></li>
</ul></div>


 <a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a>
            </nav>
```

CSS

```
nav {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  background: #86c024;
  font-size: 11pt;
  position: relative;
}
nav a {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 40px;

}
nav ul  {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width:1000px;
  width: 100%;
}
nav li  {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  height: 40px; /* this should be the same as your #main-nav height */
  position: relative; /* this is needed in order to position sub menus */
}
nav li a  {
  padding: 0 15px;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}
nav  a:hover {
  background: #2098d1;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
}
nav ul ul { /* this targets all sub menus */
  display: none; /* hide all sub menus from view */
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px; /* this should be the same height as the top level menu -- height + padding + borders */
}
nav li li a {
  border:none;
  font-size: 10pt;
}
nav ul ul li { /* this targets all submenu items */
  float: none; /* overwriting our float up above */
  width: 100px; /* set to the width you want your sub menus to be. This needs to match the value we set below */
}
nav ul ul li a { /* target all sub menu item links */
  padding: 5px 10px; /* give our sub menu links a nice button feel */
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: inline-block; /* show sub menus when hovering over a parent */
  background: gray;
  text-align: center;
  border: 0;
  z-index: 100;

}
nav li a:link, a:visited {
    color: white;
}
nav li:last-child a {
    border-right: 0;
}
nav ul li.current-menu-item a:link,
nav ul li.current-menu-item a:visited,
nav ul li.current-page-ancestor a:link,
nav ul li.current-page-ancestor a:visited {
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #2098d1;
  color: white;
}

nav #pull {
    display: none;
}  
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    nav { 
    height: auto;
    }
    nav ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    }
    nav li {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    }

    nav li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    }
    nav a {
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    text-indent: 25px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 600px) {

    nav {
    border-bottom: 0;
    }
    nav ul {
    display: none;
    height: auto;
    }
    nav #pull {
    display: block;
    background: #86c024;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    }
    nav #pull:after {
    content:"";
    background: red;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    top: 10px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {

    nav li {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    }
    nav li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #576979;
    }

}
```

Jquery

```
    $(function() {
        var pull        = $('#pull');
            menu        = $('nav');
            menuHeight  = menu.height();

        $(pull).on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            menu.slideToggle();
        });

        $(window).resize(function(){
            var w = $(window).width();
            if(w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
                menu.removeAttr('style');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: `menu.slideToggle();` is hiding the entire `nav` element when you click `#pull`. [jQuery's `slidetoggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) will toggle between shown and hidden for the matched element(s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Moob said, `menu.slideToggle();` is hiding the whole nav element when you click `#pull` element.

To get the desired effect do this

```
menu = $('nav .menu');
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4k3wuv65/)

**UPDATE**

You're menu items will be shown when the screen get resized to less than or equal 320px, because you have this css rule on your code

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {

    nav li {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
    nav li a {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #576979;
    }

}
```

Between `320px` and `600px` your menu items are covered by `nav #pull` element as you make it `display: block`, so turn it to `display:inline-block` and it'll work fine.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4k3wuv65/2/)

Comment: Thank you, its drop downs now but none of the tabs are showing because it's been covered by the menu for some reason.

Comment: You're limiting the screen size to certain width to get the menu items displayed in responsive, resize the window to `300px` and it'll show the menu items. You have to work your css media queries to make displays for the wanted minimum width of screen